# Splitting string with '<U+FF0E>' in R

Tags: r

Hello I am trying to split a dataframe column test$Name that is in this format.

```
 [1]"Fung Yat Building<U+FF0E>13/F<U+FF0E>Flat A"                                 
 [2] "Victoria Centre<U+FF0E>Block 3<U+FF0E>20/F<U+FF0E>Flat B"                    
 [3] "Lei King Wan<U+FF0E>Sites B<U+FF0E>Block 6 Yat Hong Mansion<U+FF0E>3/F<U+FF0E>Flat H"
 [4] "Island Place<U+FF0E>Block 3 (Three Island Place)<U+FF0E>9/F<U+FF0E>Flat G"   
 [5] "7A Comfort Terrace<U+FF0E>5/F<U+FF0E>Flat B"                                 
 [6] "Broadview Court<U+FF0E>Block 4<U+FF0E>38/F<U+FF0E>Flat E"                    
 [7] "Chi Fu Fa Yuen<U+FF0E>Fu Ho Yuen (Block H-5)<U+FF0E>16/F<U+FF0E>Flat G"      
 [8] "City Garden<U+FF0E>Phase 2<U+FF0E>Block 10<U+FF0E>9/F<U+FF0E>Flat B"         
 [9] "Euston Court<U+FF0E>Tower 1<U+FF0E>12/F<U+FF0E>Flat H"                       
[10] "Garley Building<U+FF0E>10/F<U+FF0E>Flat C"
```

The structure of each entry is BuildingName<U+FF0E>FloorNumber<U+FF0E>Unit. I would like to extract the building name like the following example.

```
Name                     
Fung Yat Building       
Victoria Centre   
Lei King Wan
...
```

I have tested that <U+FF0E> is actually '.' by doing this.

```
 grepl('.',"Fung Yat Building<U+FF0E>13/F<U+FF0E>Flat A")
 [1] TRUE
```

Hence, I have tried the followings but none of them worked...

```
test %>% separate(Name, c('Name'), sep = '.') %>% head 
gsub(".", " ", test$Name[1], fixed=TRUE)
sub("^\\s*<U\\+\\w+>\\s*", " ", test$Name[1])
```

Any suggestions please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easies way is to use `<` as a split pattern.

```
library(stringr)
word("Fung Yat Building<U+FF0E>13/F<U+FF0E>Flat A", 1, sep = "\\<") 


# word("Fung Yat Building<U+FF0E>13/F<U+FF0E>Flat A", 1, sep = "\\<U\\+FF0E\\>") ## building is '1', FloorNumber is '2', Unit os '3'


out:
[1] "Fung Yat Building"
```

Comment: word() is new to me, so thank you! Seems like this only works on string, so I would need to use sapply to my dataframe?

Comment: nope, its fine for vectors. such as data frame columns (i.e. in `mutate`)